# Fitting data with a convolution of continuous distributions with python

Tags: python, scipy, data-science

I need to fit a data set, which I suspect should be described by the convolution of a chi2 and a normal distribution, but the specific distributions are not the relevant matter. I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353759/python-how-to-get-the-convolution-of-two-continuous-distributions), where the accepted answer manages to convolute the two functions. I haven't managed to come up with a solution to use this for fitting. Is there a way of using a convolution of two continuous distributions for fitting in Python? I added a plot of the data and the data can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18oQ4HE4ODq0fjvFUn0_yE8Jou_rEnald/view?usp=sharing). [image]

Comment: looks close to a Gamma distribution with a shape near to 2 to me...  how would your suggestions be convoluted?

Comment: Tbh, from the process the data are obtained, I don't expect the gamma distribution here. The data show angles between lines in the 3D space, and the components of the line director vectors are derived from a fit. Regarding the question, I believe there is no analytical expression for the convolution. The link in the question points to a thread explaining how to do the convolution. My question is how to use this approach (or other) for fitting.

Comment: I don't think you want to convolve these distributions, e.g. x appears to be strictly positive which I don't see happening with a straight convolution.  chi-squared is generalised by the gamma distribution, so not sure why you're happy with chi-squared but not gamma.  I pulled some points out with webplotdigitizer and get a reasonable looking fit using a gamma with shape=2.5 and scale of 0.02 (or equivalently a chi2 with df=5 and something else doing the scaling)

Comment: I don't just need a curve that fits the distribution and looks reasonable, I need to extract parameters that I can later make sense out of them, that's why I need this special convolution, maybe you're right and I "don't want to do it" but in any case, how this helps with the technical issue of using the convolution of two continuous distribution for a fit in python?

Comment: I am facing the same question, so I am very interested in an answer. I'll post one myself if I manage to solve the problem, would be grateful if you did the same in case you managed to do it since you posted the question here. Thanks!